# Spring Boot case sensitive resolving properties from program arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a Spring boot application on my local machine. When I use the following syntax for a property it resolves well:

`username: ${project.db.user}`

However the following raises an exception:

`username: ${PROJECT_DB_USER}`

Is there any way to use uppercase here? My CI/CD pipelines defines all its variables with uppercase

Comment: I don't know the answer, but have you tried  `username: ${PROJECT.DB.USER}`?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems, and from what I've understood, since springBoot v2.1, the application.properties files don't handle environement variables well. The solution is to use Spring Profiles.
You need to add as many .properties files as you have environments, like so :

```
application.properties
application-staging.properties
application-prod.properties
```

If you have a staging and prod profiles. The .properties of the profile overrides the basic application.properties, so be sure not to forget anything in each file !

There may be other solutions as well.

You can set the profiles using various methods, in Spring boot, with Maven (sorry, the only one I'm familiar with) you can simply add it to the pom.xml like this :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <profiles>
                <profile>staging</profile>
            </profiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```